# SQL - not exists

Tags: sql, exists

I couldnt find a clear answer to this questions, should be a simple one. Basically I am trying to get all computers that dont have word installed. This query seems to be giving me wrong data. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Name
 FROM  dbo.vComputer AS v
 WHERE Name NOT IN 
                 (
                   SELECT Name
                   FROM dbo.vComputer
                   WHERE (dbo.vComputer.installedsoftware LIKE N'%word%')))
```

Comment: What's wrong about it?  Are there other strings in `installedsoftware` that contain `word`?

Comment: You could just use `NOT LIKE` and drop the subselect.

Comment: Is the field `dbo.vComputer.installedsoftware` is nullable?

Comment: So we don't know what the data in your table looks like, we don't know what data you expect to get from your query, and we don't know what wrong data you're getting instead, and you expect help? Sure, why not.

Comment: damn everyone is mad today :( Basically the data Im getting doesnt match what I am looking for. Its incorrect data. I am just looking to see if theres something wrong with the logic/syntac of the query.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results.  Your query cannot be understood out of context.

Comment: The problem with "NOT LIKE" is that it would provide the computer names that have software installed that is not "%word%" as opposed to providing a list of computers that dont have word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**With NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT Name
FROM  dbo.vComputer AS V
WHERE NOT EXISTS
                 (
                   SELECT Name
                   FROM dbo.vComputer AS S
                   WHERE S.installedsoftware LIKE N'%word%'
                 )
```

**WITH NOT IN**

```
SELECT Name
FROM dbo.vComputer AS V
WHERE Name NOT In 
               (SELECT Name 
                FROM dbo.vComputer AS S 
                WHERE S.installedsoftware LIKE N'%word%'
               );
```